# intertools combination 2 vs 2 in a list python

Tags: python, combinations, python-itertools

I need to create team of 2v2 people

here is my list of player

```
L=["P1","P2","P3","P4"]

import itertools
```

I know of to create the all `1v1` or `1v1v1` possible by using

```
>>> L=["P1","P2","P3","P4"]
>>> for p in itertools.combinations(L,2) :
...     print(p)
... 
('P1', 'P2')
('P1', 'P3')
('P1', 'P4')
('P2', 'P3')
('P2', 'P4')
('P3', 'P4')
```

or

```
>>> for p in itertools.combinations(L,3) :
...     print(p)
... 
('P1', 'P2', 'P3')
('P1', 'P2', 'P4')
('P1', 'P3', 'P4')
('P2', 'P3', 'P4')
```

but how to print all the 2V2 possible ?

Comment: What does 2v2 mean?

Comment: I want all the combinaison possible in order to create match 2 vs2 . Exemple : P1&P2 vs P3&P4, P2&P3 vs P4&P1 etc

Comment: Tell us your expected output

Comment: well I do not know the exact outut that is why I need a code for that..

Comment: Not sure if it's directly possible with itertools only.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga Counterexample: `(1, 2), (1, 3)`

Comment: @MateenUlhaq yes, stupid of me

Comment: @Grendel could there be an odd number of people under consideration?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [League fixture generator in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11245746/league-fixture-generator-in-python)

Comment: Also, see [Grouping list combinations for round-robin tournament](https://stackoverflow.com/q/32358841/7851470)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do the following, rather naively but effectively:

```
for p in itertools.combinations(L,2) :
    o = tuple(x for x in L if x not in p)
    print(p, o)

('P1', 'P2') ('P3', 'P4')
('P1', 'P3') ('P2', 'P4')
('P1', 'P4') ('P2', 'P3')
('P2', 'P3') ('P1', 'P4')
('P2', 'P4') ('P1', 'P3')
('P3', 'P4') ('P1', 'P2')
```

For more players, you can do:

```
L = ["P1", "P2", "P3", "P4", "P5"]
for p in itertools.combinations(L,2) :
    o = [x for x in L if x not in p]
    for x in itertools.combinations(o, 2):
        print(p, x)
```

Which would you give a double round-robin ;) 
For a single round-robin:

```
for p in itertools.combinations(L,2) :
    o = [x for x in L if x > p[0] and x != p[1]]
    for x in itertools.combinations(o, 2):
        print(p, x)

('P1', 'P2') ('P3', 'P4')
('P1', 'P2') ('P3', 'P5')
('P1', 'P2') ('P4', 'P5')
('P1', 'P3') ('P2', 'P4')
('P1', 'P3') ('P2', 'P5')
('P1', 'P3') ('P4', 'P5')
('P1', 'P4') ('P2', 'P3')
('P1', 'P4') ('P2', 'P5')
('P1', 'P4') ('P3', 'P5')
('P1', 'P5') ('P2', 'P3')
('P1', 'P5') ('P2', 'P4')
('P1', 'P5') ('P3', 'P4')
('P2', 'P3') ('P4', 'P5')
('P2', 'P4') ('P3', 'P5')
('P2', 'P5') ('P3', 'P4')
```

Comment: Ok and what if now I have a list of 5 players ?

Comment: @Grendel Just loop over `combinations(o, 2)`. A better name for `o` would be `remaining`, or what I presume it stands for, `other`

Comment: @Grendel so, order does not matter, e.g. `('P1', 'P2') ('P3', 'P4')` is not the same as `('P3', 'P4') ('P1', 'P2')` ?

Comment: heu yes it is the same indeed

Comment: Added the single-round robin variant, without duplicates.