# How would I assign weekly pairs from a group of people so that each pair meets and no pair meets more than once in Python

Tags: python, algorithm, optimization, scheduling

say I have a list of 6 people and want to plan quick 15 minute meetings so that everyone gets to meet everyone else once. I want to creating a scheduling algorithm so that each week, one person is paired with a new person. And by the end of however many weeks it takes, everyone has been paired with each other once.

```
people = ['Bill','Fred','Henry','Bob','Phil','Tom']

week1_pairings = [('Bill','Fred'),('Henry','Bob'),('Phil','Tom')]
week2_pairing = [('Bill','Henry'),('Fred','Bob'),('Henry','Tom')]
```

And so on and so forth until every person has met every other person.

Is there an existing algorithm/library in Python that can do this for me?

Comment: Check out Round-Robin algorithm. Maybe it helps you.

Comment: To be a bit more specific, you want to plan a round robin tournament, and there are algorithms to do that. There's a separate concept of round robin scheduling, which is an algorithm for a different problem.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [League fixture generator in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11245746/league-fixture-generator-in-python)

Answer (score 0):

You can use [itertools.combinations()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.combinations). This is possibly not the best method and is definitely not recommended when the list is large. But it gets the job done:

```
import itertools
people = ['Bill','Fred','Henry','Bob','Phil','Tom']

#Gets a list of tuples containing all possible pairs
all_pairs = list(itertools.combinations(people, 2))

#Gets a set of tuple of tuples, containing all possible weekly schedules
#However this does not ensure that the same person is not present in the same week
all_possible_weeks = set(list(itertools.combinations(all_pairs, 3)))

#Now making sure that each week has all the six unique people
schedule = []
for weeks in all_possible_weeks:
    #Counting number of unique people in each week
    count_people = len(set(itertools.chain.from_iterable(weeks)))
    if count_people == 6:
        schedule.append(list(weeks))
```